# Exchange 2007 EWSMA - Occasionally Item.Bind(Service,ItemId) fails, even when the item exists

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

Hi we have sometimes the problem that an item is not found by the **Item.Bind**(..) method.
 A **Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException** is raised with the errorcode **ErrorItemNotFound**

But when we search all folders by using **service.FindItems(folder, new ItemView(100))** and compare each id it can be found. This costs a lot of performance an resources.

Is there a known issues ? Or special cases where this does not work? Or is this a expected behavior ? Any hints what can be wrong ?

Or is there any faster / leightweight method to check wether an item exists (by itemid) ?

Many thanks for any hints.

Comment: Share your actual bind call. What is your requested [`PropertySet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.propertyset%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm from the same Company as Boas and meanwhile I found the answer. The Problem was, that I used the ItemId which I got from the PullSubscription-ItemEvent. In this ItemId a "ChangeKey" was given. And if the item Change again the Item was not found by Uniqueid and ChangeKey combination. So the solution for the Problem was to call something like this:
Item.Bind(new ItemId("")); And don't set the changekey.